# how can i show and modify style of tool-tip when i hover on the options

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

How can i show tool-tip when i hover on the option of drop-down using select drop-down?

I tried multiple ways but failed to do so

```
<ngx-select-dropdown
   (change)="selectionChanged($event)"
   [multiple]="true
   [(ngModel)]="dataModel"
   [config]="config"
   [options]="dropdownOptions"></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

Currently its not showing tool-tip, i want it show show tool-tip and change its style.

Comment: I using angular material. You can find doumentation and example here https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-tooltip)?

Comment: yes i want the tooltip for every option, but i am using ngx-select-dropdown. How can i do it with it ?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz